# stringstream >> inconsistent '\n' delimiter behaviour

Tags: c++, string, parsing, stream

I have the following function to read in a stream of text and chop it up into a vector of a given type:

```
template<class Type>
void parse_string(std::vector<Type> &type_vector, char *string) 
{
    std::stringstream stream(string);
    while (stream.good()) 
    {
        Type t;
        stream >> t;
        type_vector.push_back(t);
    }
}
```

The `char *string` parameter is a chunk of text representing either floating point numbers or strings each separated with either `' '` or `'\n'`.

Now my issue is that when given a `std::vector<float> type_vector`, the `parse_string` function will separate by both the `' '` or `'\n'` delimiters. For example for:

```
0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04
0.05 0.06 0.07 0.08
```

it will read `'0.04'` and `'0.05'` as separate tokens. This is what I want!

However if given a `std::vector<std::string> type_vector`, the `parse_string` will only separate by `' '`. Therefore if my text is as follows:

```
root_joint left_hip left_knee left_ankle
left_foot right_hip right_knee right_ankle
```

it will read 'left_ankleleft_foot' as a single token. It doesn't seem to take into account that there is a `'\n'` between `'left_ankle'` and `'left_foot'`.

What is causing this?

EDIT:

The exact char* arguments as seen in the debugger are as follows:

```
0.01 0.02 0.03 0.040.05 0.06 0.07 0.08

root_joint left_hip left_knee left_ankleleft_foot right_hip right_knee right_ankle
```

So it seems to completely ignore the '\n' from the file...

EDIT2:

Okay I figured out what I was doing wrong. As many of you pointed out, it had nothing to do with stringstream.

My parser required a std::vector copy of the file. In the process of reading the file into a string and converting it into the vector, I used the getLine(std::ifstream, std::string) function, which as you can guess, strips the '\n' newline character.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results.  Can you provide a complete example?

Comment: The stream being good does not guarantee that the extraction will be successful (I do not believe so anyway).  I would declare `Type t` outside of the loop, and then use `while(stream >> t) { }`.  Probably not related to your issue though.

Comment: Are you sure there are actually new-line chararcters in the array that you're passing to the function?

Comment: when looking at the char* strings being supplied to the function in the debugger, there is nothing between values, for example it would have '0.01 0.02 0.03 0.040.05 0.06...' or the floating point, and for the other it is 'root_joint left_hip left_knee left_ankleleft_foot right_hip...' Yet it reads the floating point values as seperate entities, while it doesnt for the strings. Does this have to do with the >> operator interpreting 0.040.05 as 0.040 and .05?

Comment: Well, then the bug is not in the code you've shown. In case of `0.040.05`, operator>> stops at the second dot, then the next call of operator>> continues there. `.05` is a valid input for float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the string incorrectly, so that \n is discarded. \n should lead to a split.